# What does this mean in C?

Tags: c

I am currently learning about the qsort function, and I encountered the compare function:

```
int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b)
{
    return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}
```

I don't understand why we are using `*(int*)a`. What is this thing, and what is its use?  Why `const void *a` instead of simple `int a`?

Comment: It sounds like you are asking the basics of the language, which is beyond the scope of this forum. Nowhere in that snippet do I see `(int)a`, which you want explained. And `*` is used to signify pointers. Please narrow your question and ask it a little more precisely. - **EDIT:** Oh, I see, you were asking about `*(int*)a` but are unfamiliar with markdown syntax.

Comment: It's a bad method anyway, since the subtraction can overflow and return the wrong comparison. Stick to that: comparison.

Comment: @user5910213 He did read it. Your original question just said `(int)a` because the `*`s were treated as markdown and you didn't check the preview to see how your question would look when rendered.

Comment: So if I use int compare(int *a, int *b) it would be alright for integer arrays?

Comment: Guys Please try to give as many possible negative signs . Thanks to all

Comment: Did you even read the SO how-to-ask page? Did you even read the man page for `qsort`? That's prob why the DVs.

Comment: Provide a [mcve] what you mean. Maybe while doing this you will see why that is a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

Since qsort is supposed to be able to sort an array of any kind of things (including structs), it passes (as arguments to its compare method) a pointer to each of the things to compare. These can be anything, so the type used is "void *" which can be a pointer to anything. Your compare method then should cast that pointer to a pointer of the correct type ( in this example, `int *` because you are comparing two ints. then you dereference that cast pointer in order to compare the values pointed to, hence the `*(int *)`

Answer (score 1):

The (int*) do a typecast to the memory address of the variable 'a' that was before a void pointer. The * before (int*) access the integer value of the memory address.
void *a is used because this is a generic function, you could use it to compare two char, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is *functionally* equivalent to this:

```
int cmpfunc(const int* a, const int* b)
{
    return(*a - *b);
}
```

In other words, `(int*)a` casts your `void* a` into an integer pointer type.

Comment: It's a bad method anyway, since the subtraction can overflow and return the wrong comparison. Stick to that: comparison.

Comment: I would assume this is just convoluted practice code which won't actually be used in anything. (I hope!)

Comment: Except that his code can be used by [qsort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/) and yours can't because it has the wrong signature.

Comment: It's not convoluted practice for the sake of it, the point is that qsort needs to accept a generic callback, so it *has* to have that generic (`void *`-based) prototype.